# How to get only numbers of a string in a link helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

## hello everyone i need your help with this.

well in my index view i have many posts with disqus comments and i show a comment counter for each post and all works fine but i get for example:

> 0 comments, 1 comment , 2 comments ... etc.

#### how can i show only the number? for example:

> 0 , 1 , 2

my helper is here:

`= link_to "", post_path(post, anchor: "disqus_thread"), data: { "disqus-identifier" => "#{post.id}" }, class: "no-underline bold blue label"`

I hope your answer thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
= link_to "", post_path(post, anchor: "disqus_thread"), data: { "disqus-identifier" => "#{post.id.gsub('comments','')}" }, class: "no-underline bold blue label"
```

Comment: hello Kumar i tried but didnt work here's my helper
= link_to "", post_path(post, anchor: "disqus_thread"), data: { "disqus-identifier" => "#{url_for([post, {only_path: false}]).gsub('comments','')}" }, class: "no-underline bold blue label"
THANKS

Comment: @JoelGarcia - you might try this: `gsub(/comment[s]*/,'')`

Comment: i could with this. Comment count link text can be customized at your Disqus Admin > Settings > Community page.
"Comment Count Link" section. Delete Comment and Comments from fields
http://disqus.com/admin/settings/community/
But now, how can i update the counter in real time in the index view, like the show view? because the counter in the index view updates some minutes later the time i commented and the counter in show view  updates in real time :( how can i resolve that? thanks

Comment: `a = '0 comments, 1 comment , 2 comments'` => `a.scan(/\d+/)
 #=> ["0", "1", "2"]` - no?